# as3 touch - analysing long touch gesture

Tags: actionscript-3, air, touch

I am making a musical instrument (mobile) where I have a rectangle that listens to user touch gestures . I would like to analyse the angle of the finger movement and play a short mp3 file in respond. I was researching and found a few options to use where I listen to the touch_end event and calculate the angle, however what I would like to accomplish is listening to one long swipe (going up , down, sideways etc.) and playing sounds accordingly.

Use case - user touches centre of the rectangle , swipes upwards , to the right , down (without removing finger) :  output - playing upSound.mp3 , playing rightSound.mp3 , playing downSound.mp3 .

putting it together (should be fast gestures):

swipes upwards : playing upSound.mp3 ,

to the right: playing rightSound.mp3

down (without removing finger) : playing downSound.mp3

user ends gesture by removing finger.

My question- is there any library or tutorial that might help me accomplish this task .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you [find that gesture angle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TransformGestureEvent.html#rotation)

Comment: Thanks , made me realize I can do a lot just with the event properties , no need for a utility to help although would be nice